# javac.exe is not recognized

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables

OS: Win7

Javac.exe is here: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin`
User variable defined as `JAVA_HOME` is this: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25`
User Variable defined as `PATH` is `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;`

I also restarted the computer. But in cmd if I say `java -version` it understands it but if I say `javac -version`, it does not recognize it.

How is this caused and how can I fix it?

Comment: What does your console see as the `%PATH%`? Do `echo %PATH%` and make sure it's actually what you think it is.

Comment: Is there a path to a regular JRE somewhere before the JDK in `PATH`?

Comment: Perhaps you need to open what's known as "Administrator Command Prompt" or open command prompt as an Administrator.

Comment: @adarshr, why should he do that?

Comment: oh it is wrong. it is 'C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin' is not recognized as an internal or exte
rnal command,
operable program or batch file.    Now what Should I do?

Comment: I echoed %PATH% and it says 'C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin' is not recognized as an internal or exte
rnal command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin;c:\program files\ibm\websphere mq\java\lib
;c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\windows live;C:\Windows\system32
;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32\wbem;C:\Windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\
;c:\program files\tortoisesvn\bin;c:\program files\windows live\shared;c:\progra
m files\microsoft sql server\90\tools\binn\;c:\progra~1\cerner;c:\program files\
ibm\websphere mq\bin;c:\program files\ibm\websphere mq\tools\c\samples\bin;c:\pr
ogra~1\java\jre16~1.0_2\bin\client;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\; C:\Prog
ram Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin;

Comment: Are those spaces in the `PATH` copy/paste errors? If not, that could be the issue.

Comment: @andyb : yes that was the issue. that fixed it. thanks

Comment: Excellent! I have added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have spaces in the `PATH`, so Windows cannot find the Java bin directory.